# How to use Support Vector Machines with Mixed data?

Tags: machine-learning, discrete-optimization

I have a dataset regarding student records with a mix of continuous, discrete & categorical data - the categorical data takes both nominal and ordinal forms.

Ex: Continuous - GPA
Ex: Discrete - Age when admitted
Ex: Categorical (ordinal) - Admit class (late freshman, early junior, etc).
Ex: Categorical (nominal) - Admit description (transfer, GED, etc).

What is the best way to apply SVMs to this dataset? The options seem to be:
1) Convert discrete & categorical values to continuous, real values before application of SVMs
2) Use appropriate similarity-based kernel for mixed data, but this I cannot find. Does it even exist?

Comment: SVM are not magic, try to understand first what they do (the linear classifier,  the soft (safety) margin, the support vectors, and the kernelized version), and the answer to your question will then be obvious : it depends.

Comment: You're rude and unhelpful. Also presumptuous.

Comment: I'm helpful : don't try to use something like the SVM if you don't know exactly how it works and why, because otherwise at some point you will be stuck wondering if you should use LDA or kernel-K-means or the SVM or a neural network. and also I'm helpful  when saying that there is no perfect/general answer to your question : it depends on your problem, your datas, your goal (as always in signal processing and machine learning)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert categorical values to binary features.
For eg, if car color was a categorical value,
Car Color = Green, Blue or Red
This value can be converted to three binary features, namely,
feature 1 (Green?), feature 2(Blue?), feature 3 (Red?)

A green car would be represented as [1,0,0] feature
A blue car would be represented as [0,1,0] feature and so on.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking to do.